# Sending PHP array to JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have an AJAX POST function that runs a PHP file that queries a MySQL database. It uses the "CONCAT" option in MySQL and then adds each row it receives into an array. I need to get that array from PHP to JavaScript, how would I go about doing this?

I've tried looking it up but nothing that I found either I didn't understand how to actually implement it, or it just flat out didn't work.

```
$sql_query = substr($sql, 0, -3);

$result = $connection->query($sql_query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid Query: " . mysqli_error());
}

$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "Total Bans: " . $rowCount . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";

$bans = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $rowCount; $x++) {
        array_push($bans, $row[$x]);
    }
}
```

I included that part of my PHP code if you need it.

I tried this:

```
echo(json_encode($bans));
```

.

```
      success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = '';
          var array = new Array();
          array = data;
          document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = array;
      }
```

That returns everything, but adds a lot of "," between them.

Example of an index in the array:

[05-18] Daedalus banned EXAMPLE_USERNAME(EXAMPLE_GUID / EXAMPLE_IP) for EXAMPLE_REASON

I want all the lines from the $bans array to be put into an array in JavaScript.

Comment: can you print what result you are getting from  echo(json_encode($bans)); statement , then only we'll have some idea to give good logics

Comment: You are printing array in html . Is that exactly you want to as o/p ? Elaborate your output .

Comment: All I get it this:

["[05-18] Daedalus banned EXAMPLE_USERNAME(EXAMPLE_GUID \/ EXAMPLE_IP) for EXAMPLE_REASON",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"[05-18] Daedalus banned TEST_SPACE_USERNAME (TEST_SPACE_GUID  \/ TEST_SPACE_IP ) for TEST_REASON_SPACE ",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,

Over and over

Comment: @suresh: I want to output each line individually due to a problem I'm having with just having PHP print out each index in the array. When I have PHP output, I add "\r\n" to the end of the echo statement, but it adds a new line depending on how many indexes there are. So if there are 18, it will add 18 new lines after each individual line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This place in your code is wrong:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $rowCount; $x++) {
        array_push($bans, $row[$x]);
    }
}
```

Because you cycle trough records with `while` and inside once more with `for`. Use only `while`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   array_push($bans, $row);
}
```

Will pull all rows and without nulls.

In your case when you have only single column in your return from database you should use:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       array_push($bans, $row[0]);
    }
```

Comment: The current code does exactly what I want it to do, and all your code does is return "Array" (I'm probably doing something wrong)

Comment: It should return array of arrays. `row` itself is an array and you push whole  array into `$bans` array. If you have only single column in your response you can use: `array_push($bans, $row[0]);`  @Daedalus i have updated answer with code for your exact case if i understood it correctly

Comment: I don't really get what the main issue is. It works just the way it's supposed to. The main issue I'm having is that PHP decides to add multiple new lines when it echos to JS. If there are 5 indexes in the array, for each echo it adds 5 new lines, and I have no idea.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at. I think this is the root cause for the issue I'm having.

Comment: The main issue is that your concept of pulling data is wrong. `while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {}` will iterate through all ROWS and in this sentence: `for ($x = 0; $x < $rowCount; $x++) {array_push($bans, $row[$x]);}` you accessing to a certain row column NOT $x ROW. In simple words variable `$row` in your case is array of certain row columns, not array of ROWS. So you try to access for every row its 0,1,2,3,4 columns, and only 0 column exists, so that's why you get 4 `null` indexes

Comment: You sir, are my hero. I've had this bug since I created this a month ago, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was causing it. What you told me to do works perfectly and solved my issue. Thank you!

(Sorry, I was confused on what exactly you were telling me in the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

When you usage `echo(json_encode($bans));` that convert php array to json array. To use json in javascript you should first Parse that array like this

```
success : function(data){
    result      =   JSON.parse(data) ;  
}
```

Now you check this data `console.log(result);`
Access particular data through key like this

```
name = result.name;
```

Comment: I tried that, however this it the output I get:

[05-18] Daedalus banned EXAMPLE_USERNAME(EXAMPLE_GUID / EXAMPLE_IP) for EXAMPLE_REASON,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,[05-18] Daedalus banned TEST_SPACE_USERNAME (TEST_SPACE_GUID  / TEST_SPACE_IP ) for TEST_REASON_SPACE ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

And so on.

Comment: From PHP:


echo(json_encode($bans));


Then in JS:


              success: function(data) {
                  document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = '';
                  result = JSON.parse(data);
                  document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = result;
              }

(Sorry, I don't know how to properly format code in comments)

Comment: Plz also share your exact  json array or what code you returning from php file to ajax function

Comment: There is no JSON array, the way the code works is it gets the return from MySQL, then adds that String to the array. I've already included the code that is returned from PHP.

Comment: when you return data from php file . you should only echo echo(json_encode($bans));  , you are also return 'echo "Total Bans: " . $rowCount . "\r\n";
echo "\r\n";' Plz remove that , plz open your console and check what data are return from php file. (press f12 key and go to console tab)